# последовательное заполнение массива из генератора чисел

Tags: c#

Нужно заполнить массив числами из генератора чисел со сдвигом на 1 элемент.
 Если было генерировано первое число то оно должно записаться в первый элемент массива а затем во второй. В первый должно записаться новое число из генератора чисел. Случайная генерация чисел не подходит.

---

Random записывает случайные числа а мне нужно что бы записал последовательно из генератора.

---

```
{
            //ask[0]=e.Volume;

        for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        ask[i+1]=генератор
```

не понимаю как правильно записать код
Random не подходит.

Comment: Сами пробовали писать? Если да, покажите код. Если нет -- здесь не решают задачи за других.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Вы не умеете сгенерировать случайное число, или не знаете, как записать число в массив? Покажите, что у вас есть на данный момент.

Comment: long[] ask = new long[22];
        
    {
       //ask[0]=a;
    
            for(i=0;i<20;i++)

Comment: добавьте код из своего ответа в вопрос. По коду я вижу что вы не знаете как правильно использовать Random, я прав?

Comment: да, и вы можете писать коментарии к своему вопросу, не плодите ответы которые не являются ответом

Comment: генератор выдает числа например 1,5,1,3...10 они должны записаться последовательно в массив

Comment: @AlexT добавил вариант решения. А вообще не ленитесь читать MSDN, там есть масса примеров по использованию стандартных классов .NET

Comment: @AlexT ну либо вам нужно писать свой генератор, но тогда это совсем другой вопрос и нужно знать правила по которым генерировать числа

Answer (score 3):

Для начала создайте генератор случайных чисел

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

После этого им можно пользоваться

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    ask[i]=rnd.Next();
```

Если принципиально необходимо записывать со сдвигом, хоть я и не понимаю зачем, то можно так

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    ask[(i+1)%20]=rnd.Next();
```